# Using the recovery console to move files off a server?

Tags: networking, server

Hosting provider has disabled "server". I still have access to SolusVM recovery console but I'm unable to reach anything but machines on the common network. I have around 800gb worth of files I need to move. Done most checks, no firewall is in place but I don't think the plugs have been pulled.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

Comment: Your hosting provider doesn't want help you for the reward you offer? That is either a very poor hosting provider or you're doing something fishy, in that case please take your "offer" somewhere else. This here is just a FAQ site.

Answer (score 2):

If the machine is powered off, and they use old school networking, you can try with Layer 2 (MAC address).
Try

```
arp -a
```

from a machine where you connected to that server previously, it should show the IP, Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) and the MAC address associated to that machine.
Then you can try with

```
wakeonlan MAC_ADDRESS
```

and if you are lucky maybe the machine powers on.

If this doesn't work, and you don't have anything better, I am sure that those 3 BTC (or the equivalent in cash) will be enough to motivate anybody in the data center to make you a backup.